# how can i create a table entry in django views

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to make a system of likes on the site, and I need to create an entry in the table on the button. When a person clicks on like, the table writes row 1 and when dislike 0

views.py

```
def forum(requset):
      model = Quetions.objects.all()
      answer = Answer.objects.all()
      count = Answer.objects.all().count()
count_answer = Quetions.objects.all().count() 
paginator = Paginator(model, 1) # Show 25 contacts per page.
page_number = requset.GET.get('page')
question_id = requset.GET.get('id',False)
page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
requestanswer = requset.GET.get('id',False)
like_disli = like.objects.filter(like_dislike = "1").count()
dislike = like.objects.filter(like_dislike = "0").count()
createlike = 
objects = {
    'model': page_obj,
    'answer':answer,
    'count':count,
    'count_question':count_answer,
    'page_obj':page_obj,
    'question':question_id,
    'id':model,
    'request':requestanswer,
    'like':like_disli,
    'dislike':dislike,
    'createlike':createlike,
    }
return render(requset,'forum.html',objects)
```

forum.html

```
 <span>
            <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up" style="color: blue;margin-right: 5px;" onclick="incrementClick()"></i>{{like}}<i class="fas fa-thumbs-down" style="color: red;margin-right: 5px;margin-left: 10px;" onclick="dislikeclick()"></i>{{dislike}} 
        </span>
{% block js %}
<script>
var a = "{{createlike}}"
function incrementClick() {
    a
}
function dislikeclick() {
    dislikedisplay(++dislikecounter);
}
function updateDisplay(val) {
    document.getElementById("counter-label").innerHTML = val;
}
function dislikedisplay(val){
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = val
}
</script> 
{% endblock js %}
```

tell me how to do it???

Comment: Can you add some more detailled informations, or - let's say - a screenshot of your html-file, so I can get an idea of what you are trying to achieve. Having problems imagining your *system*.

Comment: unless you want to be writing javascript, you may be interested to know about https://htmx.org/ which can keep all the logic in Django. Also, I assume you typed you code in here, as you've got a repeated typo in `requset` - should be `request`